# How to pipeline cleartk to ruta?

Tags: java, ruta, cleartk

[ErroR MesSagE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtRAI.png) I am using **cleartk** and **Ruta** for my project.And I want to connect ClearTk with Ruta using SimplePipeline.How can I pass ClearTk output values into Ruta Script?
Cleartk Github link is    [Github Example ClearTk](https://github.com/ClearTK/cleartk/tree/master/cleartk-examples)

And i am trying this Method

```
CollectionReader reader = UriCollectionReader.getCollectionReaderFromFiles(files);

    // The pipeline of annotators
    AggregateBuilder builder = new AggregateBuilder();

    // An annotator that reads in the file text
    builder.add(UriToDocumentTextAnnotator.getDescription());

    // An annotator that adds Sentence annotations
    builder.add(SentenceAnnotator.getDescription());

    // An annotator that adds Token annotations
    builder.add(TokenAnnotator.getDescription());

    // The POS annotator, configured to make predictions
    builder.add(ExamplePOSAnnotator.getClassifierDescription(ExamplePOSAnnotator.DEFAULT_MODEL));

    // An annotator that write out the tokens and their part of speech tags
    builder.add(AnalysisEngineFactory.createPrimitiveDescription(ExamplePOSPlainTextWriter.class,
            ExamplePOSPlainTextWriter.PARAM_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_NAME,
            ExamplePOSPlainTextWriter.DEFAULT_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY));

    /*=======================================
     * Ruta
     *======================================*/
    AnalysisEngineDescription ruta = AnalysisEngineFactory.createEngineDescription(RutaEngine.class,
            RutaEngine.PARAM_MAIN_SCRIPT, "Explico_Basic");

    // Run the pipeline of annotators on each of the CASes produced by the
    // reader
    SimplePipeline.runPipeline(reader, builder.createAggregateDescription(),ruta);

    System.out.println("Please look at the file generated by this program: "
            + ExamplePOSPlainTextWriter.DEFAULT_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY + "/2008_Sichuan_earthquake.txt.pos");
```

But it throws an Error.

my new Error Message is....

```
Sep 21, 2016 10:44:01 PM                org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl     callAnalysisComponentProcess(417)
SEVERE: Exception occurred
org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: Annotator processing failed.    
at    org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:401)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:308)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.processUntilNextOutputCas(ASB_impl.java:570)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.<init>(ASB_impl.java:412)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.process(ASB_impl.java:344)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:265)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:269)
at org.uimafit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:80)
at org.cleartk.examples.pos.RunExamplePOSAnnotator.main(RunExamplePOSAnnotator.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.FSIndexRepositoryImpl.getIndex(FSIndexRepositoryImpl.java:2465)
at   org.apache.uima.cas.impl.CASImpl.getAnnotationIndex(CASImpl.java:4544)
at    org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.updateIterators(RutaStream.java:174)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.<init>(RutaStream.java:128)
at    org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeStream(RutaEngine.java:698)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.process(RutaEngine.java:556)
at     org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:385)
... 8 more

Sep 21, 2016 10:44:01 PM         org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl processAndOutputNewCASes(273)
SEVERE: Exception occurred
org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: Annotator processing failed.    
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:401)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:308)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.processUntilNextOutputCas(ASB_impl.java:570)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.<init>(ASB_impl.java:412)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.process(ASB_impl.java:344)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:265)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:269)
at org.uimafit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:80)
at org.cleartk.examples.pos.RunExamplePOSAnnotator.main(RunExamplePOSAnnotator.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.FSIndexRepositoryImpl.getIndex(FSIndexRepositoryImpl.java:2465)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.CASImpl.getAnnotationIndex(CASImpl.java:4544)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.updateIterators(RutaStream.java:174)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.<init>(RutaStream.java:128)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeStream(RutaEngine.java:698)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.process(RutaEngine.java:556)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:385)
... 8 more

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: Annotator processing failed.    
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:401)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:308)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.processUntilNextOutputCas(ASB_impl.java:570)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.<init>(ASB_impl.java:412)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.process(ASB_impl.java:344)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:265)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:269)Sep 21, 2016 10:44:01 PM org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl callAnalysisComponentProcess(417)
SEVERE: Exception occurred
org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: Annotator processing failed.    
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:401)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:308)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.processUntilNextOutputCas(ASB_impl.java:570)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.<init>(ASB_impl.java:412)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.process(ASB_impl.java:344)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:265)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:269)
at org.uimafit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:80)
at org.cleartk.examples.pos.RunExamplePOSAnnotator.main(RunExamplePOSAnnotator.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.FSIndexRepositoryImpl.getIndex(FSIndexRepositoryImpl.java:2465)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.CASImpl.getAnnotationIndex(CASImpl.java:4544)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.updateIterators(RutaStream.java:174)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.<init>(RutaStream.java:128)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeStream(RutaEngine.java:698)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.process(RutaEngine.java:556)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:385)
... 8 more

Sep 21, 2016 10:44:01 PM org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl processAndOutputNewCASes(273)
SEVERE: Exception occurred
org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: Annotator processing failed.    
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:401)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:308)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.processUntilNextOutputCas(ASB_impl.java:570)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.<init>(ASB_impl.java:412)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.process(ASB_impl.java:344)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:265)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:269)
at org.uimafit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:80)
at org.cleartk.examples.pos.RunExamplePOSAnnotator.main(RunExamplePOSAnnotator.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.FSIndexRepositoryImpl.getIndex(FSIndexRepositoryImpl.java:2465)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.CASImpl.getAnnotationIndex(CASImpl.java:4544)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.updateIterators(RutaStream.java:174)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.<init>(RutaStream.java:128)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeStream(RutaEngine.java:698)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.process(RutaEngine.java:556)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:385)
... 8 more

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: Annotator processing failed.    
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:401)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:308)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.processUntilNextOutputCas(ASB_impl.java:570)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.<init>(ASB_impl.java:412)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.process(ASB_impl.java:344)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:265)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:269)
at org.uimafit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:80)
at org.cleartk.examples.pos.RunExamplePOSAnnotator.main(RunExamplePOSAnnotator.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.FSIndexRepositoryImpl.getIndex(FSIndexRepositoryImpl.java:2465)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.CASImpl.getAnnotationIndex(CASImpl.java:4544)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.updateIterators(RutaStream.java:174)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.<init>(RutaStream.java:128)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeStream(RutaEngine.java:698)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.process(RutaEngine.java:556)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:385)
... 8Sep 21, 2016 10:44:01 PM org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl callAnalysisComponentProcess(417)
SEVERE: Exception occurred
org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: Annotator processing failed.    
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:401)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:308)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.processUntilNextOutputCas(ASB_impl.java:570)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.<init>(ASB_impl.java:412)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.process(ASB_impl.java:344)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:265)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:269)
at org.uimafit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:80)
at org.cleartk.examples.pos.RunExamplePOSAnnotator.main(RunExamplePOSAnnotator.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.FSIndexRepositoryImpl.getIndex(FSIndexRepositoryImpl.java:2465)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.CASImpl.getAnnotationIndex(CASImpl.java:4544)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.updateIterators(RutaStream.java:174)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.<init>(RutaStream.java:128)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeStream(RutaEngine.java:698)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.process(RutaEngine.java:556)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:385)
... 8 more

Sep 21, 2016 10:44:01 PM    org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl processAndOutputNewCASes(273)
SEVERE: Exception occurred
org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: Annotator processing failed.    
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:401)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:308)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.processUntilNextOutputCas(ASB_impl.java:570)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.<init>(ASB_impl.java:412)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.process(ASB_impl.java:344)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:265)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:269)
at org.uimafit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:80)
at org.cleartk.examples.pos.RunExamplePOSAnnotator.main(RunExamplePOSAnnotator.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.FSIndexRepositoryImpl.getIndex(FSIndexRepositoryImpl.java:2465)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.CASImpl.getAnnotationIndex(CASImpl.java:4544)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.updateIterators(RutaStream.java:174)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.<init>(RutaStream.java:128)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeStream(RutaEngine.java:698)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.process(RutaEngine.java:556)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:385)
... 8 more

Exception in thread "main"  org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: Annotator processing failed.    
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:401)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:308)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.processUntilNextOutputCas(ASB_impl.java:570)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.<init>(ASB_impl.java:412)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.process(ASB_impl.java:344)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:265)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:269)
at org.uimafit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:80)
at org.cleartk.examples.pos.RunExamplePOSAnnotator.main(RunExamplePOSAnnotator.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.FSIndexRepositoryImpl.getIndex(FSIndexRepositoryImpl.java:2465)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.CASImpl.getAnnotationIndex(CASImpl.java:4544)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.updateIterators(RutaStream.java:174)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.<init>(RutaStream.java:128)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeStream(RutaEngine.java:698)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.process(RutaEngine.java:556)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:385)
... 8
at org.uimafit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:80)
at org.cleartk.examples.pos.RunExamplePOSAnnotator.main(RunExamplePOSAnnotator.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.FSIndexRepositoryImpl.getIndex(FSIndexRepositoryImpl.java:2465)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.CASImpl.getAnnotationIndex(CASImpl.java:4544)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.updateIterators(RutaStream.java:174)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.<init>(RutaStream.java:128)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeStream(RutaEngine.java:698)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.process(RutaEngine.java:556)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:385)
... 8 more
```

My sample input is...

```
2008 Sichuan earthquake
From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia

The 2008 Sichuan earthquake occurred at 14:28:01.42 CST (06:28:01.42 UTC) on 12 May 2008, with its epicenter in Wenchuan County (Chinese: ???; Pinyin: W�nchuan Xi�n), Sichuan province of the People's Republic of China. It had a magnitude of 7.8 Ms according to the State Seismological Bureau of China and 7.9 Mw according to the United States Geological Survey. The epicenter was 90 kilometres (55 miles) west-northwest of Chengdu, the capital of Sichuan, with a depth of 19 kilometres (12 mi). The earthquake was felt as far away as Beijing and Shanghai, where office buildings swayed with the tremor. The earthquake was also felt in nearby countries, such as Pakistan, Thailand, and Vietnam.

Official figures (as of May 14) state that 16,665 are confirmed dead and 66,286 injured, Thousands are missing, many of them buried, and eight provinces were affected. These figures are likely to rise sharply as a clearer picture emerges. It was the deadliest and strongest earthquake to hit China since the 1976 Tangshan earthquake, which killed approximately 250,000 people.

The epicenter was in Wenchuan County, Ngawa Prefecture, 90 km northwest of Chengdu, with its main tremor so far occurring at 14:28:01.42 CST (06:28:01.42 UTC), on Monday 12 May 2008. Early reports of the earthquake's magnitude ranged from 7.5 to 8.0. Forty-six major aftershocks, ranging in magnitude from 4.4 to 6.0, were recorded within 40 hours of the main tremor.

Office workers in Chengdu reported a "continuous shaking for about two or three minutes", and many people rushed outside.
```

My Script is.......

```
DECLARE Year;
"2008"->Year;
```

Comment: Which versions of uimaFIT and UIMA Ruta do you use?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the typesystem of the CAs does not contain the types required by UIMA Ruta, especially the type RutaBasic. Normally, with your code example, I would expect that uimaFIT (e.g., 2.2.0) automatically includes the ruta type systems. Please verify that the example code of the question is the code that causes the exception. If that is true, then there is either a problem with your uimaFIT version or with your dependencies, e.g., to ruta-core.

The prevous probem:

The problem is that the main script that should be executed by the Ruta analysis engine is not found. 
Rigth now, with this configuration of the parameters, it is expected that there is a file `MainEngine.ruta` in the root of your classpath.

(The error message indicates that the script is named Explico_BasicEngine. So your example code does not match the exception.)

You either need to place the file there, or change the parameter settings to something like `my.package.MyScript` (where is file is located in the classpath).

You can also set the configuaration parameter `scriptPaths` as a replacement for the classpath. Then, the file need to be located relative to the values of this parameter. (The classpath lookup is the fallback)

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: i edit my Question.And i clear some error Messages..but just of them still appear..

Comment: It is not good to change the question in that way because the answer is now invalid and the combination question/answer could have been useful for others.

Comment: uima ruta:2.4.0 and uimafit : 1.4.0

Comment: You should upgrade to uimaFIT 2.2.0 (or 2.1.0)